# lnamest and nameend change into colspan

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I want to change the namest and nameend attribute value into the the colspan attribute value

XML Input:

```
<row>
    <entry nameend="col2" namest="col1">Claims</entry>
</row>
```

XSL I'm having:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Expected Output is:

```
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Claims</td>
</tr>
```

If the `namest="1"` and `nameend="3"`, the `colspan` value would be `3`. It have to depend on namest and nameend values. It have to calculate the numbers from namest and nameend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to come up with an algorithm based on a single example, with no rules given. The following should work for your input above:

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:variable name="start" select="substring-after(@namest, 'col')" />
    <xsl:variable name="end" select="substring-after(@nameend, 'col')" />
    <td colspan="{$end - $start + 1}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming you are using XSLT 1.0. If you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor and your stylesheet is tagged as `version="2.0"` then you need to do:

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:variable name="start" select="number(substring-after(@namest, 'col'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="end" select="number(substring-after(@nameend, 'col'))" />
    <td colspan="{$end - $start + 1}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```